# Even in the right order the function is not defined?

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance, lazy-loading

I'm using a [lazyload](https://appelsiini.net/projects/lazyload/) function that works with jQuery.

I'm calling it in my **liga.js** file like this:

```
lazyload();
```

Now, at the footer of that page I have:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js" ></script>
<script src="/includes/jquery.lazyload.min.js"></script>
<script src="/includes/liga.js"></script>
```

As you can see my liga.js file is at the very end of the list.

I've also tried calling the function like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
lazyload();
...
```

I keep getting the error:

> ReferenceError: lazyload is not defined

Why is that?

Comment: Have you tried entering lazyload() from the console, manually, after the page is loaded? In fact, it could be an error preventing the code from finishing (and, in return, preventing lazyload from being defined.) Lemme know what's in the console

Comment: Thanks for your comment! I've just tried it typing lazyload() and I get the same error: "ReferenceError: lazyload is not defined"

Comment: Does Marin Zeitler's answer work? If not, maybe the file isn't being loaded properly.

Comment: @Drakinite there is a "Run code snippet" button, which makes the question redundant.

Comment: Whoops, my bad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the syntax with the jQuery wrapper is `$(selector).lazy()` ...

```js
$(function() {

    $('.iam').lazy({

      /* called before an element gets handled */
      beforeLoad: function(element) {
        var imageSrc = element.data('src');
        console.log('image "' + imageSrc + '" is about to be loaded');
      },
           
      /* called after an element was successfully handled */
      afterLoad: function(element) {
        var imageSrc = element.data('src');
        console.log('image "' + imageSrc + '" was loaded successfully');
      },
            
      /* called whenever an element could not be handled */
      onError: function(element) {
        var imageSrc = element.data('src');
        console.log('image "' + imageSrc + '" could not be loaded');
      },
            
      /* called once all elements were handled */
      onFinishedAll: function() {
        console.log('finished loading all images');
      }
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.lazy/1.7.10/jquery.lazy.min.js"></script>

<img class="iam" data-src="http://www.ektoplazm.com/img/escape-into-the-mirror.jpg" width="640" height="640" />
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer!! I'm trying to make it work, but for some reason is not, maybe because I'm not using *data-src* but *src*?

Comment: @Rosamunda most likely, because the `src` attribute will be loaded instantly, which subsequently will not allow lazy loading anymore (it reads from `data-src` and attaches `src`). the non-minified source code explains it: https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.lazy/1.7.10/jquery.lazy.js

Comment: Thanks again for your clarification! I've changed it but the console is saying *$(...).lazy is not a function* now

Comment: @Rosamunda are you certain the script which you load locally is the same jQuery lazyload? there are several versions of it and they may vary; my example uses the default version, loaded from CDN.

Comment: I've copied the cdn link from your example, so I guess that it should work. I'll check the cache just in case... Maybe it's because I'm using jQuery 3.3.1?

Comment: @Rosamunda updated the example to v `3.3.1` and it still works.